# $("#id").click(function(){calculation()});

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

What is wrong with the line in the header?

The below example is supposed to make a button which will increment a counter each time it is clicked. However, I enforce a delay of 2000 ms between button clicks. The version below works, however, if I use the commented out line instead of

```
document.getElementById("rollButton").onclick=function(){calculation()};
```

(both in function afterWaiting())

I get various odd results, for instance that the counter starts incrementing by a lot more than 1, and the waiting time disappears?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function afterWaiting()
        {
            $("#rollButton").css("color","black");
            //$("#rollButton").click(function(){calculation()});
            document.getElementById("rollButton").onclick=function(){calculation()};

        }

        var counter=0;
        function calculation()
        {

            ////Enforcing wait:
            document.getElementById("rollButton").style.color="red";
            document.getElementById("rollButton").onclick="";
            window.setTimeout("afterWaiting()",2000);


            counter=counter+1;
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=counter;

            }



    </script>

    </head>
<body>

  <button type="button" onclick="calculation()" id="rollButton"> Roll! </button>

<p id="test"> </p>


</body>
</html>
```

What have I misunderstood?

thanks in advance :)

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bwxb9/

Comment: Can you please a JS fiddle , and what does the console says

Comment: I'm running it through the browser, which doesn't make any complaints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only code required is

```
<button type="button" id="rollButton"> Roll! </button>
<p id="test"> </p>


var counter = 0;
var $test = $('#test');
var $rollButton = $('#rollButton');
function increment(){
    $test.html(counter++);
    $rollButton.off('click', increment);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $rollButton.on('click', increment);
    }, 2000);
}
$rollButton.on('click', increment);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/76y9Z/)

Updated: as suggested by Andy, but I would recommend Andy's answer as it involves no additional event manipulation

```
var counter = 0;
var $test = $('#test');
var $rollButton = $('#rollButton');
function increment(){
    $test.html(counter++);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $rollButton.one('click', increment);
    }, 2000);
}
$rollButton.one('click', increment);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76y9Z/1/)

Comment: i that case you could also use .one() http://api.jquery.com/one/ instead of .on(). this way you don't have to call off().

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that when you apply event handlers through `onclick` as you do in your original version, you can only bind one handler to the element. And using `onclick=""` kind of clears it.

When using jQuery `.click(handler)` you bind a new handler each time you call it (and you can unbind it with `unbind('click')` (*and not with `onclick=""`*). So after a couple of calls to `afterWaiting` you have applied mulitple click handlers on your element, and on each click the `calculation` function runs multiple times..

So, one way to correct it is to replace

```
document.getElementById("rollButton").onclick="";
```

with

```
$('#rollButton').unbind('click');
```

Comment: `and not with onclick=""` -- are you sure? How is jQuery bound to that element?

Comment: @JanDvorak it is bound using the `addEventListener` (*or `addEvent` of old IE*) which works in a different way (*read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick*)

Answer (score 2):

That's generally a bit of an odd and confusing approach.
Here's how i'd do it, without mixing jquery and pure js (onclick) too much:

http://jsfiddle.net/LGvKS/

```
var wait = false;
counter = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
    if(!wait){
        $('span').text(++counter);
        wait=true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            wait=false;
        },2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: well, I'm doing it this way because I'm learning jQuery, so trying to transition from the js version to a jQuery without breaking stuff.

Comment: @Kaare Sure, nothing wrong with that. It sounded more harsh than i intended it to be.

Comment: I think what @Andy points out here (in his code) is that you don't need to remove the event handler each time. Just set a flag (or you could disable the button) for 2 secs. And that's what I would aslo do.